# jQuery change function doesn't operate after submission error

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I used this jQuery script in a simple form **to show #x** just when the yes option is selected on the dropdown (#field1).

That works completely but the main problem is when a submission error occurs, the `#x` doesn't appear again, and the user needs to change the dropdown and select the yes field again despite it being on the yes option.

In the beginning, I used the first select code shown here below. Since the selected option was removed after the submission error, I thought the problem was with that code, and so I changed the select codes to the second snippet of code shown here.

The selected option problem is fixed now, and after a submission error, the selected option is still selected, but the **#x still does not appear**.

```
$(function() {
    $('#x,#y,#z').hide(); 

    $('#field1').change(function() {
        if($('#field1').val() == 'yes') {
            $('#x').show();
        } else {
            $('#x,#y,#z').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
```

My first dropdown codes

```
<select name="field1" id="field1" class="select-submit2">
     <option value="no">No</option>
     <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

And this is my second dropdown code, and I don't know which one is correct:

```
<select name="field1" id="field1" class="select-submit2">
    <option value="no"<? if(@$_POST['hassubunits'] == 'no') { echo 'selected = \"selected\"'; } ?>>No</option>
    <option value="yes"<? if(@$_POST['hassubunits'] == 'yes') { echo 'selected = \"selected\"'; } ?>>Yes</option>
</select>
```

`#x` should appear after the submission error

Comment: You can trigger the `.change()` event when the page first loads, so it will run the change event listener.

Comment: Removed the jQuery Validate tag since this seemingly contains nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please avoid tag-spam.  Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar could you please guide me how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the `.change()` event listener immediately after loading the page, by calling `.change()` after defining the handler.

```
$(function() {
  $('#x,#y,#z').hide();

  $('#field1').change(function() {
    if ($('#field1').val() == 'yes') {
      $('#x').show();
    } else {
      $('#x,#y,#z').hide();
    }
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this,

```
<select name="field1" id="field1" class="select-submit2">
         <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
   <p id="x">This is p tag</p>
   <span id='y'>This is span tag</span>
   <div id="z">This is div tag</div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $('#x,#y,#z').hide(); 
                            $('#field1').change(function(){
                                if($('#field1').val() == 'yes') {
                                    $('#x').show();

                                } else {
                                    $('#x,#y,#z').hide(); 
                                } 
                            });
   });
```